# Is a power series with integral coefficients with a limit at x=1 a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

If we have a power series with integral coefficients $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i$ which converges for all $|x|<1$, and the limit as $x\rightarrow 1$ exists, where we approach along the real axis from the left, can we conclude $f$ is a polynomial?

The idea being that the existence of such a limit forces the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i$ to converge, and integrality gives the result, but setting up this limit is proving difficult.

If it helps, we can assume $f(x)$ is positive on $[0,1)$, and dominated by a positive polynomial on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Consider $\sum_n(-1)^nx^n$ which equals $(1+x)^{-1}$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: @WimC why did you post an answer as a comment?

Comment: Why quibble? @NajibIdrissi

Comment: @WilliamElliot Because the question will remain "unanswered" for the system if no one answers it.